# White shadow on top of map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using styled Google maps, night style from [mapstyle](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). On a certain tilt and zoom a white thing appears on top. [image: problem when tilted and zoomed] On different zooms ant tilts everything is fine.[image: no problem when tilted and zoomed] Any ideas how this can be fixed?